# Encrytion and Decryption without using a cipher instance or key

Tags: java

Does any one know how to encrypt and decrypt a string without using a key or cipher, A simple encryption which takes input as string and then when i want i call decrypt function to decrypt it where input is as encrypted string.

Comment: How do you mean encrypt? Obfuscation? You could use an encoding like Base64.

Comment: As you've seen from the answers so far, what you're asking for won't provide much security. Can you tell us more about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's hardly encryption - as soon as an attacker can call the "decrypt" function, your secret is gone.
You *could* use a standard encryption algorithm, and call it with a key built-in in the code - but I do *not* recommend it. Especially since the key in the code would be visible to anyone who can access your code, compiled or not.

Comment: first thing is i need a basic encryption, my application is in house, also i am using  SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey(); first time i encrypt using AES, i use this while decrypting i need to use the same skey how will i get this, suppose if i want to store this key in some file any idea

Comment: I store my keys and passwords in PasswordSafe. There are other tools for storing keys and passwords as well; look for some on the net. Most of them are also able to generate passwords that you can use as encryption keys. You can then give the passwords to those users in-house who have need of them.

Answer (score 2):

If your crypto doesn't use a key, a random pad, or a secret of some sort then it can only be secure if the algorithm is secret and unguessable.  When you rely on the algorithm staying secret, you're relying on security by obscurity which has a really poor track record.

I know key-exchange can be a PITA, but it's the only way to prevent eavesdropping by any semi-competent attacker.

Answer (score 1):

Try [ROT13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13), it is as secure as this will get. No real encryption though.

You can embed your encryption/decryption key in your application and you won't have anything  to do with it. But your encryption will be as secure as you store it - not really secure. And anyone can disassemble the application and call your decrypt routine.